# Refreshing the ADFS token periodically in web page

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, ws-federation, azure-acs

I am new to ADFS. We are using ADFS token for our security purpose. But our application is single page application and we don't go to server many times, we cache the data on client mostly. So while working on the page users face expired ADFS token after some time. This is because user has not refresh the page for a long period of time. 
   Is there a way in ADFS to call the ADFS API in ADFS periodically and refresh the token in html page?

Comment: I have found the solution for this. I used http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.sessionauthenticationmodule.sessionsecuritytokenreceived(v=vs.110).aspx API and I got all the control over the session expiration. We have to use reissue cookie after setting validfrom and validto property in the seesion token.